# Vitest, Vue Test Utils not replacing custom component with implementation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, vue-test-utils, vitest

I have been trying to implement a component test using Vitest and Vue Test Utils. Currently my issue is that the component does not replace the custom component with the component implementation.

This is my test file:

```
import { describe, expect, test } from 'vitest';
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import VInputPhone from './InputPhone.vue';
import Input from '../Input.vue';

describe('InputPhone.vue', () => {
  test('Should render input with type tel', () => {
    // Arrange
    const vModel: string = 'Input Value';

    const VInput = mount(Input, {
      shallow: true,
      props: {
        modelValue: vModel
      }
    });

    const wrapper = mount(VInputPhone, {
      global: {
        components: { VInput: VInput }
      },
      props: {
        modelValue: vModel
      }
    });

    console.log(wrapper.html());

    // Act & Assert
    expect(wrapper.find('input').attributes().type).toBe('tel');
    expect(wrapper.find('input').attributes().type).not.toBe('text');
  });
});
```

My InputPhone.html has the following structure:

```
<div>
  ...
  <VInput></VInput>
  ...
</div>
```

However using my above implementation VInput is not replaced, this is the rendered output when I log the wrapper html:

```
<div class="...">
  <vinput type="tel" modelvalue="Input Value"></vinput>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? I have looked through the docs but can't seem to find an answer to my problem.